# Unable to convert 'matlab.ui.Figure' value to 'int64' with matlab base64 encoder

Tags: matlab, base64

I am trying to convert an an image in matlab to a `base64` encoded string but when I used the base64 image encoder found at this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24514-base64-image-encoder), I ran the encoder on an image and got this error:

Unable to convert 'matlab.ui.Figure' value to 'int64' with matlab base64 encoder

```
Error in base64img (line 35)
print(sprintf('-f%i',fig),'-djpeg',sprintf('-r%i', dpi), file);
```

The error was found in this code:

```
if nargin == 0
    %use the top figure if none specified
    fig = gcf;
end
if nargin < 2
    %use 75-dpi if none specified
    dpi = 75;
end
%the easiest way to get the figure's data in jpeg format is to save it as
%temporary jpeg and clean it up afterwards
file = [tempname '.jpg'];
print(sprintf('-f%i',fig),'-djpeg',sprintf('-r%i', dpi), file);
base64string = base64file(file);
delete(file);
if nargout == 0 
    %if no output args, create a web page to display the image and show it
    s = sprintf(['<html><head><title>Matlab Figure: %i</title></head><body>'...
        '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,%s"></body></html>'],...
        fig, base64string);
    web(['text://' s]);
end
```

Comment: You’re trying to serialize a graphics object? Try `savefig` instead. The base64 encoder you found, I presume, converts a numeric matrix to base64, not a graphics object.

Comment: I am interested in ultimately converting an image matrix to base64 and then uploading this data to a firebase server in json form using the webwrite function. Would the ```savefig``` function work for this purpose?

Comment: So then put the image matrix into the base64 encoder, not a handle to the figure where the image is displayed!

Comment: Sounds like you need to [`print`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) your figure to a bitmap file, then read that file in (you'll then have a numeric image matrix, not a MATLAB figure object) and do whatever you want with it